# How to change delegate's property during transition

Tags: qt, qml

I try to change property "opacity" in delegate (Rectangle as delegate), but get ReferenceError: rectDelegate is not defined.
How do I refer to the desired model index in the delegate to change the property?

```
    Item {
        id: root
        
        QtObject {
            id: internal;property int rectHeight: 16 * 3
        }
    
        GridView {
            id: grid
model: 12; anchors.centerIn: parent; height: internal.rectHeight * 2; width: internal.rectHeight * 6    
cellWidth: internal.rectHeight; cellHeight: internal.rectHeight
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: rectDelegate
    
                color: "green"
                opacity: {
                    switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                    case 2:
                    case 5:
                        return 1
                    case 6:
                 ...
                    }
                }
                width: internal.rectHeight
                height: internal.rectHeight
            }
        }
    
        states: [
            State {
                name: "first"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rectDelegate
                    opacity: {
                        switch (rectDelegate.index) {
                        case 0:
                      ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "second"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rectDelegate
                    opacity: {
                        switch (rectDelegate.index) {
                        case 0:
                       ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: "first"
                to: "second"
                PropertyAnimation {...}
            },
            Transition {
                from: "second"
                to: "first"
                PropertyAnimation {...}
            }
        ]
    
        Timer {
            ...
            onTriggered: {rectDelegate.state = "second"}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Currently you have `states`, `transitions` and `Timer` as a part of `Item`. You can consider moving this element to be a part of delegates `Rectangle` - then, you will have an access to the desired property.

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way. You shouldn't try to manually access every delegate to change their properties. You should update your model instead. The model could hold an opacity value for each item.

Comment: You can probably also use `Behavior on <property>` construct instead of the transition code

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid using JS-code (and `switch`s) in QML as much as possible. The more declarative code you have - the better.
- Try to move values for opacities of your delegates to array in `internal`.

Here is fixed & 'compilable' code (with my additions in places where `...` was)

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    Item {
        id: root

        state: "first"

        QtObject {
            id: internal;
            property int rectHeight: 16 * 3

            property var opacities: [0.7, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.7, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1]
        }

        GridView {
            id: grid
            model: 12; anchors.centerIn: parent; height: internal.rectHeight * 2; width: internal.rectHeight * 6
            cellWidth: internal.rectHeight; cellHeight: internal.rectHeight
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: rectDelegate

                color: "green"
                opacity: internal.opacities[index]
                Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
                width: internal.rectHeight
                height: internal.rectHeight
            }
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "first"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: internal
                    opacities: [0.7, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.7, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1]
                }
            },

            State {
                name: "second"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: internal
                    opacities: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 2000
        running: true
        repeat: false

        onTriggered: root.state = "second";
    }
}
```